# How to get first element of a list inside dictionary and add to Pandas Dataframe column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {"key 1": ["val 1", "val 2"],
        "key 2": ["val 3", "val 4", "val 5"],
        "key 3": ["val 6", "val 7"],
         ...
}
```

I also have a pandas dataframe that contains all the keys like this:

```
     key
0    key 1
1    key 2
2    key 3
...
```

I need to add a new column to the dataframe called first_key that takes the first element of the list inside the dictionary for each key in the dict, so it ends up like this:

```
     key      first_key
0    key 1    val 1
1    key 2    val 3
2    key 3    val 6
...
```

which I have had some trouble with... doing something like this doesn't work:

```
df['first_key'] = df['key'].map(dict[WHAT HERE][0])
```

:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    "key 1": ["val 1", "val 2"],
    "key 2": ["val 3", "val 4", "val 5"],
    "key 3": ["val 6", "val 7"],
}

df["first_key"] = df["key"].apply(dct.get).str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     key first_key
0  key 1     val 1
1  key 2     val 3
2  key 3     val 6
```

---

Or:

```py
df["first_key"] = df["key"].map(dct).str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
new_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in your_dict.items()}

df['first_key'] = df['key'].map(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and `.str[0]`:

```
df['first_key'] = df['key'].map(dict).str[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     key first_key
0  key 1     val 1
1  key 2     val 3
2  key 3     val 6
```